# Process getInputStream() never ends

Tags: java, makefile

In my program, I'm trying to execute a `make` through Java code.

Here a part of my listing:

```
this.makefileGenerator.generate();

Process proc = this.makefileGenerator.runCompiler();

//this.stream.println(IOUtils.toString(proc.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println("\n" + line);

try {
    int result;

    if ((result=proc.waitFor()) == 0)
        this.stream.println("Done!");
    else {
```

The execution seems to be blocked during the `proc.getInputStream()` call. In fact, my program does not crash but never terminates.

In the console output I have:

```
make: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/cr01046/Documents/workspace/ocelot/jni'
gcc -shared -m32 -D__int64=int64_t -LC:/gtk/lib -lintl -mms-bitfields -IC:/gtk/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtk/lib/glib-2.0/include  -IC:/'Program Files'/Java/jdk1.8.0_73/include -IC:/'Program Files'/Java/jdk1.8.0_73/include/win32  -o ../Test.dll  lists.c ocelot.c EN_CBridge.c main.c -lglib-2.0
```

I also have tried to throw the `make` through the prompt and the compilation terminates correctly (however, with several warnings). I does not understand why in this situation the `make` works, while through Java it does not terminate.

Comment: How do you _know_ it's blocked in `getInputStream()`?  I would split up that set of nested calls into individual statements to confirm where it's blocked.

Comment: Your `System.out.println` instruction seems to work, so the problem is not on the reader creation part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compilation generates warnings, but you don't see the warnings when run from Java, then the warnings are written to STDERR, and you are not consuming STDERR. Depending on the amount of error output, the make process may have stalled when the buffer runs full.

If the `Process` was created using [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), then you should call [`redirectErrorStream(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28boolean%29) to merge the error output with the standard output.

Comment: My `make` process in fact was stalled by a lot of warnings on STDERR. Thanks for the explanation